# Why AI doesn't vary his strategy?

Tags: starcraft-2

Sometimes I play custom games versus A.I. in order to fine-tune an opening, to warm-up, etc.

I often play as Terran, however when playing against a Zerg the A.I. *ALWAYS* chooses a 1 base roach strategy. I've gotten to the point where I can beat it with any opening.

I am trying to force myself to play against it as if it is playing a Fast Expand (FE), or 6 pool, or anything else (I invest hard in marines, go to banshee, do FE myself), but in any case, I am still subconsciously prepared to counter a roach attack at around 6 minutes.

**Is there any way to force the A.I. to vary it's strategies?** For example, it can play a roach rush, but it would be nice if it could do at least some scouting and (for example if some marauders are detected) expand and use existing roaches to keep expand instead of attempting to destroy wall/bunker/marauders.

Comment: So I don't know if it has changed, but I've definitely had the Brutal AI switch up his strategy against me and go for a verity of openings (though never seen a 6 pool).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

While I'm not sure about the specifics of how the AI works behind the scene or whether or not there are tactics you can use to force the AI to switch his strategy to something else, I know that [YABOT](http://www.sc2mapster.com/maps/yabot/) in Advanced mode allows you to choose what build order the AI should perform. You can make or import build orders for the AI to use against you, along with setting the AI difficulty.

Comment: Can I set 'random' BO for AI with YABOT?

Comment: @Budda Yes, there is a Random Build checkbox.

Comment: You might want to look into Green Tea AI, which is included in YABOT, but not part of it. You can usually find maps with Green Tea in bnet by searching for "+GTAI +18b", where 18b is for the latest version 1.18b.